# SQL minimum of average

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

For a query I need to select the records that are 'minimum of average'. So in theory I should do something like

```
select min(avg(x)) from tableA;
```

Since nested aggregation functions are not supported I'm not sure how to achieve this. I tried subquery's as wel, but I never could make it work so anyone an idea? Pseudo code is enough, I don't need a full solution. That's why I used pseudocode myself and not giving the data I'm working on.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Since it's required to give example/sampledata:

I have 3 tables where I need to get the part, employee and duration from.
I need the query to be grouped by part & employee and need to get the minimumaverage of duration.

```
SELECT p.part, e.Name, min(avg(s.duration)) as AvgDuration
FROM store s
JOIN parts p
ON p.PartId = s.PartId
JOIN employees e
ON e.EmployeeId = s.EmployeeId
GROUP BY p.PartNr, e.Name
ORDER BY PartNr;
```

I know that this is a faulty query but that should make clear what I'm aiming for.

Based on the solution of Gordon,

I have following query:

```
SELECT m.PartNr, m.Name, min(avg_duration) as Duration
FROM (
    SELECT p.PartNr, e.Name, avg(s.Duration) as avg_duration
    FROM Store s
    JOIN parts p
    ON p.PartId = s.PartId
    JOIN employees e
    ON e.EmployeeId = s.EmployeeId
    GROUP BY p.PartNr, e.Name
) m
GROUP BY m.PartNr, m.Name;
```

But what this does is for each employee give the minimum avg, while only the employee with the minimum should be shown.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Added an example

Comment: You still failed to make clear what you mean by minimum average. Do you want the average duration per part and employee and of all these the one minimum value?

Comment: As to your query: What is `m`? Which table does `duration` reside in?

Comment: CROSS APPLY to a query that calculates the AVERAGE for you

Comment: m should be s, wrong copy paste on my side @ThorstenKettner

Comment: Hm, this doesn't seem to make sense. That datamodel would then suggest that a store has only one employee (store.employeeId) and one part (store.partNr). Strange stores. And the duration is in which table? What does it represent?

Comment: And can I find the same EmployeeId + PartNr multiple times in store? Otherwise your `GROUP BY` would do nothing. So again: You haven't explained what average and what minimum you are really talking about. The average per ___? And then of all these the one minimum value?

Comment: multiple employees, how should it suggest only one? The store table keeps partid & employee id which i use to join them. And the 'repair' duration is in the store table.

Comment: For employee id & part id is unique. They have multiple parts to repair, employees can repair same parts multiple times. Each time has a duration, of each part I need to get the employee with the shortest avg repair time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it by using sub-query and  then use min function .from discussion i got the problem and found it needs below query

```
select t2.PartNr,t3.Name,Prt_minDuration from 
(
select m.PartNr,min(Duration) as Prt_minDuration from
(
SELECT m.PartNr, m.Name, min(avg_duration) as Duration
FROM (
    SELECT p.PartNr, e.Name, avg(s.Duration) as avg_duration
    FROM Store s
    JOIN parts p
    ON p.PartId = s.PartId
    JOIN employees e
    ON e.EmployeeId = s.EmployeeId
    GROUP BY p.PartNr, e.Name
) m
GROUP BY m.PartNr, m.Name
) t1 group by PartNr
) t2

inner join 
(
SELECT m.PartNr, m.Name, min(avg_duration) as Duration
FROM (
    SELECT p.PartNr, e.Name, avg(s.Duration) as avg_duration
    FROM Store s
    JOIN parts p
    ON p.PartId = s.PartId
    JOIN employees e
    ON e.EmployeeId = s.EmployeeId
    GROUP BY p.PartNr, e.Name
) m
GROUP BY m.PartNr, m.Name
) t3 on t2.PartNr=t3.PartNr and t2.Prt_minDuration=t3.Duration
```

Comment: this shows only the total minimum average. I need to have the minimum average per employee

Comment: @JC97 just use name of employee and group by name i edited answer

Comment: that works better. Altough I need group by part as well (See the query I added to the question I've made based on Gordon's answer.

Comment: Congratulations. Now you posted the answer that I had 20 mins ago :) Stil not the right one tho.

Comment: @JC97 do you need top minimum one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177571/discussion-between-zaynul-abadin-tuhin-and-jc97).

Answer (score 4):

The minimum of the average doesn't make sense, unless you are aggregating by something.  I would expect something like:

```
select min(avg_x)
from (select avg(x) as avg_x
      from t
      group by ?
     ) x;
```

Comment: added query based on this solution in the question